# Server Operator on csgo

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

why i get this error when use cheats in offical matchmaking in csgo says example: sv_cheats 1      Can't change replicated sv_cheats 1 from console of client, only server operator can change its value and godmode not working in matchmaking only in paractice bots

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about cheating in multiplayer games.

Comment: We don't give support for cheats here. But please don't cheat, you're just ruining the game for everyone else. If you want to use cheats go to a single player game.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `sv_cheats 1` on official servers, because, as the response said:

> You are not an operator.

... Admin, basically.

---

If you want to run cheats, you'll want to get your own server or play single-player.
You can't just waltz onto a random server you don't own and change settings you aren't allowed to change, just like you can't just waltz into a random person's house and completely repaint their walls.